# Spring 5 MVC - InternalResourceViewResolver and Spring Security

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm learning Spring, and I've got stuck on some issues i can't resolve. I run it on a GlassFish Server.

I'm implementing a simple WebMvcConfigurer which has an InternalResourceViewResolver, it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return resolver;
   }

   @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource() {
      ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      source.setBasename("messages");
      return source;
   }

   @Override
   public Validator getValidator() {
      LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
      validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
      return validator;
   }
}
```

and my Controller:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/")
@Controller
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

I would assume that when I run the app, it would open the `index.jsp` file, but it doesn't, instead I get a 404. When I change it to

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

it opens it.

Also, I've followed the documentation on [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration) and implemented simple security. From my understanding, every request should be authenticated and it should redirect the user to a login page, but it doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("user").roles("USER").build());
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ApplicationConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
    }



    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        // you might want to add stuff to enable spring security


        return new Filter[]{characterEncodingFilter};
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

I'm suspecting that the issues are related, but can't see what I'm missing here. When i change the path in the Controller as mentioned above, I do not get redirected to the login page.

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.vives</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-quickstart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring-mvc-quickstart</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <!-- Override Spring version -->
        <spring.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.1</jackson.version>
        <thymeleaf-extras-java8time-version>3.0.1.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-java8time-version>
        <!-- AssertJ is not a part of Spring IO platform, so the version must be provided explicitly -->
        <assertj-core-version>3.8.0</assertj-core-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <!-- Avoid issue #72 Could not initialize class org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver due to 'validation is not supported' -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>pull-parser</artifactId>
                    <groupId>pull-parser</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally resolved the issues I had.

As for security, i forgot to add [SecurityWebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc) and as for navigation, [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) link helped me.